# How to use cylindrical co-ordiantes ?

Tags: integration, volume

Q. Find the volume of wedge intercepted between the cylinder $x^2+y^2=2ax$ and the planes $z=x$ and $z=2x$

I am not able to make out how to find its volume using cylindrical co-ordinates in this case. I know the basics of cylindrical co-ordinates but basically not able to apply it to find limits of the integral. some tips on that would be very helpful

thanks

Comment: If you first make the swap $x' = (x-a)$, the equation for the cylinder says $x'^2 + y^2 = a^2$, so in cylindrical coordinates, this would be $r = a$ (just remember the new origin is at the old $(a, 0)$). This means the planes become $z = x' + a$ and $z = 2x' + 2a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the circle in polar coordinates is $r=a \cos{\theta}$.  Thus we may set up the integral in cylindricals as

$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \int_0^{2 a \cos{\theta}} dr \, r \, \int_{r \cos{\theta}}^{2 r \cos{\theta}} dz $$

This ends up simplifying to

$$\frac{16 a^3}{3} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \cos^4{\theta}$$

I get $\pi a^3$ as the volume.

Comment: why did we not take the limit for $r$ from $1$ to $2$ ?

Comment: Because the circular cross-section is not centered at the origin.  The equation of the circle is as I stated in my solution.

Comment: Thanks ! i have my concept clear now.

Comment: I had been doing this integral by shifting center, but I had been getting $\pi a^3$ and I didn't post it. Now come to think of it, should't that second limit be $2 a \cos(\theta)$ since the circle is of radius $a$ and is centered at $(a,0)$ as in [this picture](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%3D2+cos%28theta%29)?

Comment: @experimentX: you are right, many thanks for pointing that out.